# Chevrolet Aveo lt sedan won't start or even click...it ain't the battery or the fuses..what could be the problem?

Tags: starting, chevrolet, aveo

I have a 2008 aevo Chevrolet and it won't start...it won't even click and it's not the battery or the fuses so what is the problem?? I'm a women so I don't know these things...I'm learning though..thanks for any help out there,!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Why do you think it's "not" the battery? Do the dash lights light up? Can you turn the headlights on? What exactly happens when you turn the key to the on position?

Comment: If the battery is really dead it won't even click FWIW...

Comment: Tell us *how* you know it isn't the battery. Are other things working?